# sql order by rand() with highest value shown more frequently

Tags: mysql, sql, vbscript

As title describes, im looking to write some SQL (mySQL DB) thats displays random records with highest value shown more frequently then others.

```
select CPC from advertisement ORDER BY RAND(), CPC DESC
```

The above code does not work as expected.

heres what im after:

I have 10 advertisers each setting their own cpc (cost per click) budget. The advertiser with the heighest budget will have his/hers advert show more frequently then the others, yet all being random.

```
user_id | cpc  |
------------------
1       | 0.10 | 
2       | 0.03 |
3       | 0.20 |
4       | 0.04 |
5       | 0.55 |
6       | 0.12 |
```

So user 5 will have his advert displayed more freqently then the others
5, 3, 6, 1, 4, 2 - in order of most impressions respectively.

Bit like I assume google adwords work, the higher the users budget the more impressions he/she will have.

I know no one likes RAND() due to performance but I will have no more then 100 advertisers.

Regards

Comment: Could you please share some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it? It's a bit hard to understand the question ATM (to me, at least)

Comment: I vote for 'this is beyond the scope of MySQL' and should be done at the application level, where it would be very straightforward.

Comment: You could use  `order by RAND() * CPC` (or any other function depending on cpc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the best way to do this would be like so:

```
SELECT user_id, CPC
FROM advertisement 
ORDER BY RAND() * CPC DESC
```

This will make your adverts appear randomly, but user_id 5 will theoretically appear 5.5x more frequently than user_id 1, which is fair.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this seems to work perfectly, what different would RAND() + CPC DESC vs RAND() * CPC DESC make?

Comment: `RAND + CPC` would be unfair. If you get the max RAND for 0.1, it would be 1.1, and the max rand for 0.5 would be 1.5... With this method, 0.1 is MUCH more likely to be able to out-do 0.5, as 0.5 is only 50% more likely than 0.1 to get picked... With multiplying, it's fair. Since they are paying 5 times as much for a click, they are 5 times MORE likely to get a click.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and great explanation. This works as expected. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Because your `cpc` is less than 1, you can do:

```
select CPC
from advertisement 
order by RAND() + CPC DESC
```

This tweaks the `cpc` value, so higher values should appear higher on the list.